# Scala function to accept Java maps from Java code

Tags: java, scala, collections, dictionary, scala-java-interop

I have a mixed Scala/Java project. I'm trying to write a Scala function that would accept **either** Scala maps (from Scala code) or Java maps (from Java code) - java.util.HashMap for a start.
Here's what I came up with (Scala code):

```
def test[M <: scala.collection.Map[String, Any] with java.util.HashMap[String, Any]] (m: M): Int = { ??? }
```

and trying to call it from Java code like this:

```
HashMap m = new HashMap<String, Character>();
m.put("key", 'V');
ScalaCode.test(m);
```

which gives me a compile-time error:

```
[javac] /home/username/test/JavaCode.java:79: error: method test in class ScalaCode cannot be applied to given types;
[javac]                         ScalaCode.test(m);
[javac]                                  ^
[javac]   required: M
[javac]   found: HashMap
[javac]   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[javac]     inferred: HashMap
[javac]     bound(s): HashMap<String,Object>,Map<String,Object>
[javac]   where M is a type-variable:
[javac]     M extends HashMap<String,Object>,Map<String,Object> declared in method <M>test(M)
```

**Edit:** I changed the assignment to

```
HashMap<String, Character> m = new HashMap<String, Character>();
```

trying to appease Java type inference, no luck - now it says:

```
[javac]   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[javac]     inferred: HashMap<String,Character>
[javac]     bound(s): HashMap<String,Object>,Map<String,Object>
```

**Edit:** Subtyping from java.util.Map does not help:

```
def test[M <: scala.collection.Map[String, Any] with java.util.Map[String, Any]] (m: M): Int = { ??? }
```

produces

```
[javac]   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[javac]     inferred: HashMap<String,Character>
[javac]     bound(s): scala.collection.Map<String,Object>,java.util.Map<String,Object>
```

What is wrong with a type bound for M?

Comment: `X <: Y with Z` means "`X` is a subtype of **both** `Y` and `Z`".

Comment: Any way to implement **OR** logic here?

Comment: There is the `Either` class in the scala standard library, but you need to explicitly tag whether your object is a `Y` or `Z`. It can't be any other way unless `Y` and `Z` have a common base type, because at some point you need to know which methods you can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better idea to have the function accept the lowest common denominator, in this case `java.util.Map`, so that your Java code doesn't have to jump through hoops to use it. Scala maps can be converted automatically with a simple import of `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`.

With the following Scala:

```
def test(map: java.util.Map[String, Character]) = ???
```

Your Java code can call the method normally:

```
test(new HashMap<String, Character>());
```

And any other Scala code can use `JavaConversions` for automatic conversion:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
test(Map.empty[String, Character])
```

Comment: Just a note, if you're going down the conversion route it's better to use `scala.collection.JavaConverters` and call `asJava` and `asScala` directly rather than loading up all those implicits.

Comment: I considered mentioning `JavaConverters` as well, but went with the implicits from `JavaConversions` because that approach provides the kind of seamless integration he was looking for with in the original question.

Comment: I played around with JavaConversions._, but they do not seem to work in function arguments (at least when calling from Java code) - compiler just says that it expects another type.   Can you give example of how to make it work here?

Comment: Implicits only work in Scala, which is why I suggested making your function accept `java.util.Map` -- your Java code could then call it without any extra steps, and your Scala clients only need to import the implicit converter from `ScalaConversions`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I didn't think to `import JavaConversions._` in **client** Scala code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaConverters to achieve this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.{ HashMap => JMap }
import scala.collection.mutable.{ Map => MMap }
```

Now for a better approach:

```
implicit class JavaMutableConverters[K, V](map: MMap[K, V]) extends AnyRef {
  final def asMutableJavaMap: JMap[K, V] = {
    val hash = new JMap[K, V]()
    for ( (k, v) <- map) { hash.put(k, v) }
    hash
  }
}
```

This will work with any `K, V` combo.

```
object TestMaps {

  def test(map: JMap[String, Any]): JMap[String, Any] = {
    map.put("string", "test")
    map
  }

  def test(map: MMap[String, Any]): JMap[String, Any] = {
    test(map.asMutableJavaMap)
  }
}
```

Never do casts or use `instanceof`, in the interop case the rule of thumb is to stick to the lowest common denominator.

```
 val x = new JMap[String, Any]();
 x.put("test1", "test2")

 val y = MMap[String, Any]("test1" -> "test2")

 println(TestMaps.test(x))
 println(TestMaps.test(y))
```

Comment: After trying it out:  
1) toScala can be applied only if type parameters of the map are specified `def test (map: JMap[String, Any]) = { ??? }`;  
2) This function does not accept instances of java.util.HashMap - expecting java.util.Map;  
3) More importantly, it does not accept Scala maps. As stated in the question, I need this function to accept **either** Java or Scala maps - hence the attempt at defining a type bound.

Comment: not sure what you mean by overloading here. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok, that works for the maps of type [String, String], stops working when I put [String, Any] (I need that!) - when I pass a Java map [String, Int] it says that test expects Map[String, Any].  
Also, I would prefer not to use this Java-ish solution, defining a type bound looks a lot cleaner, so I would like to understand what am I doing wrong with it.  

P.S. How can I put line breaks in comments? Double space isn't working.

Comment: Ok, that works (and when calling from Java, I need to declare HashMap as `HashMap<String, Object>` to get Java's auto-wrapping of primitives). I'd still prefer Scala-like solution with type parameter, any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score -4):

```
object ScalaCode {
    def test(map: AnyRef) {
        if (map.isInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap]) {
            //your code here
        } else if (map.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.Map]) {
            //your code here
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's a really bad idea. You should never encourage anyone to step around the type system this way.